# Retrieve uri path from net.Conn

Tags: go, tcp, request

I'm working with someone else's code and I need some assistance.

Here we have a tcp load balancer. What I need is access to the request uri from this piece of code **before we do the net dial**.

I looked through the API Documentation here: https://golang.org/pkg/net/ but was unable to find any relevant methods under the `net.Conn` namespace for retrieving the current request path.

```
func copy(wc io.WriteCloser, r io.Reader) {
    defer wc.Close()
    io.Copy(wc, r)    
}

func handleConnection(us net.Conn, backend BA.Backend) {
    if backend == nil {
        log.Printf("no backend available for connection from %s", us.RemoteAddr())
        us.Close()
        return
    }           

    ip:=us.RemoteAddr().String()
    parts:=strings.Split(ip,":")
    ip=parts[0]

    //w := bufio.NewWriter(us)
    //w.WriteString(+"\n")
    //w.Flush()    
    ds, err := net.Dial("tcp", backend.String())
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to dial %s: %s", backend, err)
        us.Close()
        return
    }

    // Ignore errors
    go copy(ds, us)
    go copy(us, ds)
}

func tcpBalance(bind string, backends BA.Backends) error {    
    log.Println("using tcp balancing")
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", bind)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to bind: %s", err)
    }

    log.Printf("listening on %s, balancing %d backends", bind, backends.Len())

    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("failed to accept: %s", err)
            continue
        }        
        go handleConnection(conn, backends.Choose())
    }

    return err
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a "request path" or URI in TCP. You need to find another way to pass in the information.

Comment: I removed the tcp term. i just need access to the request path inside the handleConnection function

Comment: Changing the wording doesn't change the fact that a bare TCP connection has no notion of a URI. URIs are layer 7, your socket is layer 4.

Comment: @Adrian so theres no way to obtain the request path prior to the tcp net dial. how does it successfully pass the request to the api instances in my tcp code and return a response?

Comment: It's in the layer 7 payload. The path would be in the HTTP request line (e.g. `HTTP/1.0 GET /users/jkushner`) and the hostname would be in the Host request header.

Comment: @Adrian I see. So the apis are able to see because its in the http request line.

Comment: Why the downvote here? This seems like a valid question...

Comment: Note that there's also HTTP 1.1, HTTP/2 and QUIC. Also note that once you read something off your network stack it's now your responsibility to handle that payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible because not every TCP connection is an HTTP connection and the TCP protocol has no concept of URIs. Many other protocols are built on TCP and it's not that protocol's responsibility to know about them.

HTTP is an [Application Layer (layer 7) protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer) which uses the [TCP Transport Layer (layer 4) protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer). As such, TCP connections have no concept of HTTP because lower layer protocols have no concept of the layers that may be built on top of them.

You can learn more by reading about the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).

Comment: It isn't "likely not possible", it's just not possible, though HTTP isn't the only protocol that uses URIs (see: FTP, SQL, IRC, email, etc).

Comment: @Adrian I changed the wording to be more precise.